# creating html by javascript DOM (realy basic question)

Tags: javascript, dom

i'm having some trouble with javascript. Somehow i can't get started (or saying i'm not getting any results) with html elements creation by javascript.

i'm not allowed to use:

`document.writeln("<h1>...</h1>");`

i've tried this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body').appendChild('h1');
document.getElementsByTagName('h1').innerHTML = 'teeeekst';
```

and this:

```
var element = document.createElement('h1');
element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('text'));
```

but my browser isn't showing any  text. When i put an alert in this code block, it does show. So i know the code is being reached.

for this school assignment i need to set the entire html, which normally goes into the body, by javascript.

any small working code sample to set a h1 or a div?

my complete code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A boring website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="createDom.css"> 


    <script type="text/javascript">

    var element = document.createElement('h1');
element.innerHTML = "Since when?";

document.body.appendChild(element);


    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The first one will not work, the second one will if you add the element to the document. I recommend to read the [MDN introduction of DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Introduction#What_is_the_DOM.3F).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you append the element to document?

Much the same way you're appending text nodes to the newly created element, you must also append the element to a target element of the DOM.

So for example, if you want to append the new element to a `<div id="target">` somewhere are the page, you must first get the element as target and then append.

```
//where you want the new element to do
var target = document.getElementById('target'); 
// create the new element
var element = document.createElement('h1');
element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('text'));
// append
target.appendChild(element);
```

Comment: That will probably throw `Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3`. You can't append elements directly to the body.

Comment: when i add this: 'document.appendChild(element);' to my second code sample it still won't work. could you write me a working smaple which for example creates an h1 tag into the body with te text: "sample h1" ?

Comment: @Quentin : Yes, I'm aware. It was a typo in my answer. I've expanded the answer as well.

Comment: @FelixKling : I didn't put in the `body` reference.

Comment: @Felix Kling — Since I tested [the original code](http://jsfiddle.net/trA6X/) in Chrome.

Comment: I actually didn't see what you wrote before, I guess I just misunderstood @Quentin then (or he phrased it poorly ;))... *Edit:* Yeah, I thought you were talking about `document.body`, nvm.

Comment: It wasn't helped by me typoing "body" when I meant "document", damn memory muscle.

Comment: i used the "since when" example which clearly works in your online sample. but when i put in in my document and open it in chrome or internet explorer. I'm still not getting any results. i'll add my entire code (since it isn't much)

Comment: @middelpat: At the time you execute the JavaScript code, `document.body` does not exist yet. Put the script at the end of `body`.

Comment: @FelixKling that worked, thank you. i was getting a huge headache from this.

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a **NodeList** (which is like an array of elements), not an element. You need to iterate over it, or at least pick an item from it, and access the properties of the elements inside it. (The body element is more easily referenced as `document.body` though.)

`appendChild` expects an **Node**, not a string.

```
var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
var content = document.createTextNode('text');
h1.appendChild(content);
document.body.appendChild(h1);
```

You also have to make sure that the code does not run **before the body exists** as it does in your edited question.

The simplest way to do this is to wrap it in a function that runs onload.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    var content = document.createTextNode('text');
    h1.appendChild(content);
    document.body.appendChild(h1);
}
```

… but it is generally a better idea to use [a library](http://microjs.com/#events) that abstracts the various robust event handling systems in browsers.

Answer (score 1):

create element, add html content and append to body

```
var element = document.createElement('h1');
element.innerHTML = 'teeeekst';
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

Comment: to me it looks like this should also do the trick. but when i paste it in my html document and open it in the browser i'm still getting a blank page with only a title in the tab.

Comment: add the javascript on the end of the page, just before ``</body>``